# What permissions are needed to access INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Tags: sql-server

What permissions are needed to access [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in MSSQL?

My test user on a newly created test database has been assigned as database owner so he can do whatever he wants. But I'd like to figure out, what rights a database user needs to have to read information from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Thanks!

Comment: Each view in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is different. For example the `COLUMNS` view will allow anyone to query it, but will only return columns that the user can access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions for each view in [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are different, you need to check the individual help for each one.

For example the [`TABLES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view docs state:

> Returns one row for each table in the current database for which the current user has permissions.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I guess that will be the same for views, etc.
But in general everyone is able to query the views of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` without errors but they may all be empty if the user has no permissions?